# How do I log in to Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I just got the minecraft exe and I can't figure out how to log in, does anyone else know how to do this? I already tried looking up and down and clicked everywhere and I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: Did you get this from the Mojang website?

Comment: A screenshot would help here.

Comment: You have to buy Minecraft first

Comment: Could you give us more detail please?

Comment: Is your Minecraft updated to the newest version? Have you even officially bought the game?

Answer (score 6):

First you need to buy the game here: https://minecraft.net/store/minecraft
Then you have to download the client here: https://minecraft.net/download
Then run minecraft.exe it will ask for password and email. Log in and click play!